# Google Custom Search initial value

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have created a Google Search function, however I would like to leave the textfield blank instead of this appearance:-

[image]

It is possible? Thanks!

Comment: yes it is, what have you tried?

Comment: @Dagon, I have tried to look at the js (http://www.google.com/jsapi), however I cannot see any codes controlling the words display; also, the CSS seems no help. I believe it is the default setting of the function by Google...

Comment: sorry you can move but not remove the branding, at least not with out breaking the TOS. http://googlecustomsearch.appspot.com/element/layoutdemo/branding_style.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using the stock custom search embed code, add the following to your CSS:

```
form#cse-search-box div input {
    background-image: none !important;
}
```

Comment: just be carefull as it breaks the TOS

Comment: @Dagon, what is TOS?? Is it refer to terms of service? Thanks!

Comment: Terms Of Service, the contract you agreed to in order to use the code. Unless you paid for the business version in witch case it's ok to remove the google branding. http://www.google.com/cse/docs/branding.html

Comment: Terms of Service. What you agree to to use their product